# Function Is Not Running

Tags: python

Just started to code, can't figure out why the `start` function will not ask me for any user input.

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,6)

def start():
    print("Do you want to start?")
    answer = raw_input("Type 'Yes' to start!")  #Asks me for user input... Doesn't work
    if answer == "yes":
        print("Rolling the dice... The number is... " + number)
    else:
        print("Aww :( ")
```

Comment: the problem has obvisouly nothing to do with "input".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the function.

```
start()
```

Working script:

```
import random

number = random.randint(1,6)

def start():
    print("Do you want to start?")
    answer = raw_input("Type 'Yes' to start!")
    if answer == "yes":
        print "Rolling the dice... The number is... ", number
    else:
        print("Aww :( ")

start()
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to give consideration to your program as a module.

Try making the following changes:

```
import random

_NUMBER = random.randint(1,6)

def start():
    print("Do you want to start?")
    answer = raw_input("Type 'Yes' to start!")
    if answer == "yes":
        print("Rolling the dice... The number is... " + _NUMBER)
    else:
        print("Aww :( ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start()
```

The ["if **name**"... addition](http://effbot.org/pyfaq/tutor-what-is-if-name-main-for.htm) allows your program to be run from the interpreter as a module. You can also import this module into other programs easily.

I've also changed the syntax on your global variable (number) to reflect best practices. It's now private -- indicated by the underscore -- and uppercase.

If this program is imported as a module, the global variable won't impact those of the same name.

Now you can do `python filename.py` from the command line, or `from filename import start` and `start()` from the interpreter to run your program.

Answer (score 2):

You never actually call the function:

```
number = random.randint(1,6)

def start():
    print("Do you want to start?")
    answer = raw_input("Type 'Yes' to start!")
    if answer == "yes":
        print("Rolling the dice... The number is... " + number)
    else:
        print("Aww :( ")

start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Just like the other two said, you haven't called the function "start()". Also you asked to type "Yes" but you check if the user gave "yes".